# WinForm Hosted ComboBox Leave Event does not fire within WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, events

I added the the Both from Code behind with `cb.Leave += new EventHandler(cb_Leave);` or design by `Leave="cb_Leave"` but none of them worked. is it a bug or what?

Examined LostFocus event instead and this one also has malfunction and does not fire correctly every time.

I also added KeyPress event to my hosted control but it is working correctly.

Comment: _" is it a bug or what?"_ - most likely _"what"_. [The First Rule of Programming: It's Always Your Fault](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/)

Comment: Why not use a WPF combo box?

Comment: @MickyD Yeah but the first rule of WPF/winforms interoperability is that it might not necessarily be your fault after all.

Comment: @ed-plunkett because of winform combobox suggest append capability

Comment: @JDM Fair enough.

Comment: What is not working?  You state "none of them worked".  How do you expect it to work? I put a combo box and a text box on the form and when I switch from one to another, the leave event is fired properly.

Comment: @John Koerner The Leave Event of WinForm ComboBox hosted in WPF Not working. But now using LostFocus event for its parent WindowsFormsHost satisfied my wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `LostFocus` Event for its parent WindowsFormsHost satisfied my wish.